# Bash output different when in the console compared to when in an array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have the following csv file *mydata.csv*

```
Afghanistan,Incidence,2018,29
Viet Nam,Incidence,2017,27
United States of America,Incidence,2016,26
United Kingdom,Incidence,2015,15
```

I want to extract the countries, which is easy by using cut, giving me the following output in the console:

```
$ cut -d "," -f 1 mydata.csv

Afghanistan  
Viet Nam  
United States of America  
United Kingdom
```

However, when storing it inside an array:
`myArray=($(cut -d , -f 1 mydata.csv))`

Here is what I get:

```
$ echo "${myArray[@]}"  
Afghanistan Viet Nam United States of America United Kingdom
```

Calling `echo "${myArray[3]}"` gives me **"United"** instead of **"United States of America"**.

So instead I have tried to use `awk` to add quotes around each country and store them inside an array.

```
$ awk '{print $0}' mydata.csv | cut -d , -f1 | awk -v q="'" '{print q $0 q}'
```

Gives me the following inside the console:

```
'Afghanistan'  
'Viet Nam'   
'United States of America'  
'United Kingdom'
```

But again, when I store it inside an array using this line of code:

```
myArray=($(awk '{print $0}' mydata.csv | grep -v Location | cut -d , -f1 | awk -v q="'" '{print q $0 q}'))
```

I get the following broken up array once again:

```
$echo "${myArray[2]}"
Nam'
```

I have no idea what to do to get **'Viet Nam'** (instead of **Nam'**) as a single element or **'United States of America'** as well.
Why are the outputs correct in the console and weirded up when in an array?

Comment: `Why are the outputs correct in the console` Are you sure you are using Bash?

Comment: Use newline as the field separator `IFS` when creating the array. By default any whitespace is the field separator.

Comment: Or use the `readarray` command.

Comment: When you use `$( )` without double-quotes around it (as in your array definition), it's split into *words*, not lines. (And potentially worse, it's also subject to wildcard expansion.) Use `readarray -t`, or see [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: @GordonDavisson I added the double-quotes around it for my array, but now all the lines are inside the first element of my array, myArray[0]. Using readarray does read the lines properly but I cannot pass my trim arguments to it. Using a for loop to do it is immensely slow (as my dataset is quite large).

Comment: If you want to deal with structured data, `bash` is not the language to choose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read lines into an array, word-splitting is not particularly useful. You need to either use `readarray` (aka `mapfile`) or a `while read` loop. If you want to take data from a command (e.g. `cut`) rather than a file, you need to combine that with process substitution:

```
readarray -t myArray < <(cut -d "," -f 1 mydata.csv)
```

Note that both `readarray` and process substitution are nonstandard bash features, so you need to run your script with bash. Use a bash shebang (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), and don't override that by running the script with the `sh` command.